# Bucket fill tool fills screen with teal instead of FG color

Tags: gimp

I want to fill the layer with the white color but when I use the bucket fill tool, it paints the layer with a random (it looks like to me) teal color.

Take a look:

[image]

How do I fill the layer with the FG color?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate this problem. Can you check your Channels panel and make sure all the Channels are enabled before using the Bucket fill tool. It's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Hey. I "fixed" that problem by restating GIMP so lost the channels configuration. However, I'm 100% sure it'll happen again and I';ll paste the channels config here.  Thanks @BillyKerr

Comment: If you sample the color, you will see that it's RGB=(0,255,255), ie, your Green and Blue channels are deselected (if you are painting black over a currently white layer).